# "To call" vs. "to ring"

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs, telephone

What is the difference between the verbs "call" and "ring" in the meaning of telephoning? For example:

> - I will ring you back shortly.
> - I will call you back shortly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two words are identical in meaning here. The usage of *call* is obvious, while the usage of *ring* simply originated from the noise a telephone makes when you call someone.

*Ring* is definitely a more informal word, so if in doubt, use *call*.

Comment: Regional variation - In the US, prefer "I'll call you back shortly" over "I'll ring you back shortly". In my experience, we (Americans) never say "I'll ring you back." We do, however, frequently say, "I'll give you a ring," but this is quite informal.

Answer (score 12):

*Ring* is generally used in the UK, while *call* is used in the US.  There's no difference in meaning.

Comment: I'm British, and I'd be more likely to say "call". To me, "ring" feels slightly old-fashioned.

Comment: This is not a UK-US distinction. I've heard plenty of Americans use *ring* and British use *call*.

Comment: Never ever heard an American say this, unless they affected a goofy British accent and ended with "Cheerio!"

Answer (score 5):

*Ring* is very common in Australia and New Zealand, and probably somewhat frequent in the U.K. and Ireland, but *call* is basically always used in the U.S.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard "give * a ring" in the US, but never "ring *"